# How to Subset xts file with date object?

Tags: r, date, subset, xts

I searched for quite a while on this question, but can't find an answer. The challenge is finding a way to subset an xts file by date with the form:

```
 dat <- xts(1:10, as.Date("2000-01-01")+1:10)
 date.1 <-as.Date("2000-01-05")
 dat.subset <-dat[date.1/]
```

This doesn't work, of course, and neither do variations, such as:

```
dat.subset <-dat["date.1/"]
```

How can I subset with the date.1 object to produce the equivalent of:

```
dat.subset <-dat['2000-01-05/']
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
dat.subset <-dat[paste0(date.1, "/")]
```

Comment: This is exactly what I'm looking for. Perfect.  Thanks much!

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
require(xts)
dat <- xts(1:10, as.Date("2000-01-01")+1:10)
date.1 <-as.Date("2000-01-05")
dat[date.1,1] #The row name is date.1
```

Comment: This only subsets one value rather than mutiple values.